# Determine which ASP.NET MVC View to return when not using return View(model) but return View("viewName", model)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mobile, view

I have my mvc site working well with mobile and non-mobile browsers; the issue I'm having is this. I have a couple Actions that (for logging reasons) I don't want to do a `return RedirectToAction(...);` on so instead I had been using `return View("OtherView", model);` this worked until I tried it on mobile, and it doesn't find OtherView.Mobile.cshtml. Is there a way to make this work?

Thise are the views

```
Views/Account/Create.cshtml
Views/Account/Create.Mobile.cshtml
Views/Account/CreateSuccess.cshtml
Views/Account/CreateSuccess.Mobile.cshtml
```

This is the Action

```
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection form)
{
    TryUpdateModel(model);

    if(!ModelState.IsValid) { return View(); }  // this works correctly

    var model = new Account();

    var results = database.CreateAccount(model);

    if(results) return View("CreateSuccess", model); // trying to make this dynamic

    return View(model); // this works correctly
}
```

Normally I would just do `return RedirectToAction(...);` to the account detail page, but this will generate an additional log entry (for this user being read) as well as the detail page does not have access to the password. Since `ActionResult Create` had the password originally, it can show it to the user for confirmation, before its never seen again.

To be clear, I do not want to do `if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice) mobile else full` because I may end up adding another set of mobile views for for iPad or whatever:

```
Views/Account/Create.cshtml
Views/Account/Create.Mobile.cshtml
Views/Account/Create.iPad.cshtml
Views/Account/CreateSuccess.cshtml
Views/Account/CreateSuccess.Mobile.cshtml
Views/Account/CreateSuccess.iPad.cshtml
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just set a session variable on their first usage that would be a "delivery type" identifying all supported views.

```
public enum DeliveryType
{
    Normal,
    Mobile,
    Ipad,
    MSTablet,
    AndroidTablet,
    Whatever
}
```

Then you could have a property or extension method somewhere

```
public DeliveryType UserDeliveryType
{
    get 
    {
        return (DeliveryType)Session["DeliveryType"];
    }
    set 
    {
        Session["UserDeliveryType"] = value;
    }
}
```

You could even put in a different method to delivery the View "add on":

```
public string ViewAddOn(string viewName)
{
    return (UserDeliveryType != DeliveryType.Normal) ?
        string.Format("{0}.{1}", viewName, UserDeliveryType.ToString()) :
        viewName;
}
```

Then your ultimate call could be:

```
if (results) return View(ViewAddOn("CreateSuccess"), model);
```

Then you'd just have to make sure that for every delivery type you have a corresponding view. It may be prudent to build some kind of checker to verify you have a matching view and if not return the standard view.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a pseudo-view that has a Partial with a ViewData variable. @Html.Partial will find the correct view.

something like this:

```
CustomView.cshtml:
if (ViewData.ContainsKey("PartialViewName")) {
@Html.Partial(ViewData[PartialViewName]);
}

Controller.cs:
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection form)
{
    TryUpdateModel(model);
    ViewData[PartialViewName] = "CreateSuccess";
    if(!ModelState.IsValid) { return View(); }  // this works correctly

    var model = new Account();

    var results = database.CreateAccount(model);

    if(results) return View("CustomView", model); // trying to make this dynamic

    return View(model); // this works correctly
}
```

you can have now CreateSuccess.cshtml and CreateSuccess.Mobile.cshtml.

note: you only need ONE CustomeView.cshtml in your all your application.

note2: you can always pass parameters in another fashion like viewbag, or whatever technique makes you feel more confortable :D

It's more a bit of hack than a solution. Let us know if you came up with something prettier.